# Convert string version of list to list

Tags: string, list

How would I convert this back into a list?

```
myList = ["Hello", "World"]
stringList = str(myList)

ConvertBackToList(stringList)
```

Comment: What language? If [tag:python], see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894269/3001761. And Please Don't Write Everything In Title Case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)